# Check box in list view listener

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create a listener on a checkbox of a list view such that when I click on the checkbox in the list only it'll do something not when I click on the listview item.

Answer (score 4):

This is your solution:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle *) { 
  super.onCreate(*); 
  setContentView(R.layout.checkboxeamample); 

  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01); 
  cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                                            boolean isChecked) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
      if (buttonView.isChecked()) { 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Checked", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      } 
      else 
      { 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "UnChecked", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      } 
    } 
  }); 
}
```